# Python - Pebble - misunderstanding of the timeout feature

Tags: python, concurrency, timeout

After reading the Pebble's documentation (https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/), it seems quite simple. Nevertheless, I can't get the expected result.

I started from an example given on their web site

```
import time
from pebble import concurrent, ProcessExpired
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError

@concurrent.process(timeout=10)
def function(foo, bar=0):
    time.sleep(5)
    return foo + bar

future = function(1, bar=2)

try:
    result = future.result()
except TimeoutError as error:
    print("function took longer than %d seconds" % error.args[1])
except ProcessExpired as error:
    print("%s. Exit code: %d" % (error, error.exitcode))
except Exception as error:
    print("function raised %s" % error)
    print(error.traceback)
else:
    print(str(result))
```

My understanding:

1. a timeout of 10 seconds has been set for the function
2. the future.result() blocks until result is ready
3. it will take around 5 seconds for the function to execute
4. you will go directly to the ***else*** "branch" of the ***try / except*** and get the printed result that is to say "3"

In fact, I never get the desired result but instead the message "function took more than 10 seconds".

Can you tell me what I missed to get the expected result (i.e. foo + bar)?

Comment: This code works for me. What operating system are you using? What version of Python?

Comment: I am using Python 3.2 under Windows 7

Comment: I would highly recommend you to upgrade your Python version as 3.2 is really old and has few issues with modules like `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

`pebble` doesn't support python 3.2, I'd recommend upgrading to a version greater than or equal to 3.6 (the current minimum supported version).

Source https://github.com/noxdafox/pebble/blob/master/setup.py#L27

```py
    python_requires=">=3.6",
```